# Working on genetics calculator, not getting the results I expect from my arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a genetics calculator which sort of works, however not as I intend it to haha.

I am using the following code:

```
<?php

function getGeneArray($geneString) {
    // check the argument for fitting your needs!
    if ( strlen($geneString) % 2 == 1 ) {
         die('Supplied geneString is not made of pairs!'); // better not die - handle errors according to your application methodology
    }
    // add additional error-catching (there are only certain possible base-pairs, if something else is found you should reject the string

    $genes = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ( $i < strlen($geneString) )
    {
        $genes[] = substr($geneString, $i, 2);
        $i += 2; // Here is your mistake, you just $i++
    }
    return $genes;
}

function combinePairs($A, $B) {
    // uppercase genes build the string first, which means B must be uppercase to come first and A cant be uppercase -- no longer important
    if ($A !== $A && $B === $B) {
        return $B.$A;
    } 
    return $A.$B;
}   

$gene1 = 'bbEe';
$gene2 = 'bbEe';

$geneA = getGeneArray($gene1);
$geneB = getGeneArray($gene2);

$possibilities = array();
foreach ($geneA as $A) {
    foreach ($geneB as $B) {
        $possibilities[] = combinePairs($A, $B);
    }
}
```

The output from running the above code is:

`Array ( [0] => bbbb [1] => bbEe [2] => Eebb [3] => EeEe )`

When in reality I would like it to be something like:

`Array ( [0] => bbee [1] => bbEe [2] => bbEE )`

What can I do/change to get the right sort of outcome?

Comment: `if ($A !== $A && $B === $B)` $A === $A always, and $B === $B, so that expression is always false.  What are you testing?

Comment: @James That's a bit of code for an older version that i should probably remove it as it's not required

Comment: So, is there an updated `combinePairs` function?

Comment: I can't figure out how the desired result data you posted is generated from pairs like "bb","bb" and "bb","Ee".  Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first function can be simplified somewhat using `str_split`

```
function getGeneArray( $str ) {
    if ( strlen( $str ) % 2 == 1 ) die('Supplied gene string is not made of pairs!');
    return str_split( $str, 2 );
}
```

As for the `combinePairs` function it appears that it will only ever return `$A.$B` - without knowing HOW the calculations are supposed to work it is hard to give an answer.

I don't know if this is how the `combinePairs` function was supposed to be

```
function combinePairs( $A, $B ) {
    return strtolower( $A )!=$A && $B===$B ? $B.$A : $A.$B;
}
```

Of possible interest in regards to calculating the sequences ( based upon your comments of `"uppercase genes build the string first"` then the `ctype_*` family of functions might be useful.

```
`ctype_lower( $str )` ~ tests if ALL characters in $str are lowercase.
`ctype_upper( $str )` ~ tests if ALL characters in $str are uppercase.
`ctype_alpha( $str )` ~ tests that all characters in $str are Alphabetic.
```

And to test if a string contains an Uppercase character you can do:

```
if( strtolower( $str ) != $str ){/* contains an uppercase character */}
```

Comment: I need to clean the combinepairs up as it's not actually required at the moment. Will review this when i'm home :)

Comment: I will edit my post tomorrow and try and explain a bit better what i'm trying to do

Comment: This gave me a good basis to work on, have a working system now thank you

Comment: Glad that it helped! What was the final solution?

Comment: In all fairness it's expanded into a bigger system, but the `ctype` functions above helped me with my plans :)